# Installing Bun on WSL - Unsupported platform

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, bun

This Bun is strange. Windows is the same, PC is the same. On one Ubuntu distribution the installation is successful, on another Ubuntu - Bun says Unsupported platform. What will be the versions of this behavior?

```
adminl@DESKTOP-R2SDNHI:~$ uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-R2SDNHI 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

adminl@DESKTOP-R2SDNHI:~$ bun -v
1.0.0
```

```
ubuntu@DESKTOP-G3UBQ67:~$ uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-G3UBQ67 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ubuntu@DESKTOP-G3UBQ67:~$ npm install -g bun
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for bun@1.0.0: wanted {"os":"darwin,linux","cpu":"arm64,x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","cpu":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid os:   darwin,linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual os:  win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid cpu:  arm64,x64
npm ERR! notsup Actual cpu: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-12T10_33_27_055Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the npm version, 8.19.2 does not install, 9.6.7 installs

Answer (score 0):

The propery way to install is mentioned in the docs [here](https://bun.sh/docs/installation#macos-and-linux)

```
curl -fsSL https://bun.sh/install | bash # for macOS, Linux, and WSL
```